# How to call CICS programs from C#

Tags: c#, cics, cobol.net

We currently call CICS Main frame programs via Cobol.net using the CICS universal client.

We are wondering if it is possible to call them directly from C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Accessing CICS from Microsoft .NET applications using CICS Transaction Gateway](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/1012_crockett/1012_crockett.html?ca=drs-)

Answer (score 3):

CICS v3 and later does SOAP and REST web services, if that's direct enough for your purposes.

Answer (score 2):

I'll chime in with [Host Integration Server](http://connect.microsoft.com/HISERVER). I used to use it and it works quite well.